# XFS disk error in Ubuntu Server 11.04 / how to automount on hot plug

Tags: ubuntu, xfs

I was running Fedora 14 with 2x1TB firewire drive attached. It always mounted good, though sometimes after a long inactivity stopped opening, which was always solved by re-plugging it.

I should add that is has built-in RAID capabilities, and it was configured for RAID0. I don't actually remember if I did something special for it after I formatted it to XFS from Fedora.

Ubuntu (as seen below) is showing there are 4 partitions (sdb{1..4}), and partition sdb3 mounts well.

But I wonder
1) how should I fix the bad magic number message from dmesg (see below)

2) what is the proper way to reliably configure auto-mount for this disk. Fstab with `/dev/sdb3` is not something I like, I would prefer configuring the same mechanism desktop Ubuntu uses for hot-plug mounting - is it `udev` or what?

dmesg:

```
[  819.940470] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[  819.940566] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] START_STOP FAILED
[  819.940573] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BUS_BUSY driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  819.940772] firewire_sbp2: released fw1.0, target 4:0:0
[  819.941943] firewire_sbp2: released fw1.1, target 5:0:0
[  823.615962] firewire_core: phy config: card 0, new root=ffc1, gap_count=5
[  823.878052] firewire_core: phy config: card 0, new root=ffc1, gap_count=5
[  824.157381] scsi7 : SBP-2 IEEE-1394
[  824.158374] scsi8 : SBP-2 IEEE-1394
[  824.158511] firewire_core: created device fw1: GUID 0090a99500a35518, S400
[  824.384893] firewire_sbp2: fw1.0: logged in to LUN 0000 (0 retries)
[  824.400372] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Book          1015 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[  824.400776] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  824.411058] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 3907017568 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[  824.416006] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  824.416014] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 10 00 00 00
[  824.419127] firewire_sbp2: fw1.1: logged in to LUN 0001 (0 retries)
[  824.421267] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Cache data unavailable
[  824.421274] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  824.444172] scsi 8:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       My Book Device   1015 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[  824.444336] ses 8:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
[  824.444530] ses 8:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 13
[  824.452811] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Cache data unavailable
[  824.452819] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  834.653467]  sdb: [mac] sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 sdb4
[  834.693116] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Cache data unavailable
[  834.693124] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  834.693210] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  882.728314] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, large block/inode numbers, no debug enabled
[  882.729897] SGI XFS Quota Management subsystem
[  882.730863] XFS: bad magic number
[  882.730866] XFS: SB validate failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The error was resolved by itself after several successful mounts
2. Use: `/dev/disk/by-uuid`